# How to make a rotating gradient (on a circle)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gradient

I create a simple circle with the arc function:

```
/* ctx is the 2d context */ 
ctx.beginPath();
  var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, this.radius, this.radius);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FF0000');
  gradient.addColorStop(1, '#FFFFFF');
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;

  ctx.arc(this.radius, this.radius, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
  ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
ctx.stroke();
```

So I want to rotate the gradient, is that possible?
I've tried with *ctx.rotate(x)* but that rotates the whole circle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your gradient is going from `x1,y1` to `x2,y2`, which are the four last arguments of `createLinearGradient`

For example, to reverse your gradient do this:

`var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(this.radius, this.radius, 0, 0);`

Or change it up however you please:

`var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(this.radius, 0, 0, 0);`

And so on.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not really understand the second coordinates x2 and y2. Should I pass the circumference?

Comment: You merely use the two points of where you want the gradient to start and end. So right now yours is starting at the top left and ending at radius,radius. Where do you want it to start and end?

Comment: The gradient should be expanded on the whole circle, so I must set radius.
I've experimented a bit, but how can I do a loop? I mean what is when the x and y are equal to radius?